# Outlook for Mac lacks add-in command button group labels

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-for-mac

Outlook add-in manifests are supposed to work on PC Desktop Outlook, OWA and Outlook for Mac. That mostly seems to be the case but we noticed an issue with Outlook for Mac. Outlook for Mac does not appear to have button group labels.

Look at the Microsoft Store red briefcase "Store" button for example. In Windows Desktop Outlook this button is in the Add-ins button group as indicated by the text "Add-ins" as the label below the button. For Outlook for Mac the button group label is missing. In fact Outlook for Mac appears not to have any button group labels at all.

If you are just adding a single add-in command the associated button image can be your logo. What if however, you have two or more add-in commands in a button group with your product name as the Label? This can be confusing for the user if the product name is missing. For example what if one of your add-in commands is labelled "Tools"? Without the button group label the user might get confused. Tools for what?

How do we make this look good for Outlook for Mac? What are people doing to get around this? Is there a best practices solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, we have stopped support for ribbon group titles on Outlook Mac.

The best way out is to have the app name as part of the command - if X is the name of the app, have "X Tools", instead of just "Tools". We recommend that you do not rely on the group title to communicate the product name.

An example of this is Boomerang, which has its button label as "Open Boomerang" instead of just "Open".